# ng-click inside templateUrl directive not woking

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-click

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'm a new to `Angular`. I have an `ng-click` event that worked before I put the code in a directive. I understand it's probably to do with the scope, but can't seem to fix it.

I have an html file I reference from `templateUrl`:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <p class="title">{{ flight.origin }}</p>
    <p class="title">{{ flight.destination }}</p>
    <p class="title">{{ flight.airline }}</p>
    <p class="date">{{ flight.deptime | date: 'medium' }}</p>
    <p class="date">{{ flight.arrtime | date: 'medium' }}</p>
    <p class="price">{{ flight.price | currency }}</p>
    <div class="pax">
        <p>Adults: {{ flight.paxadult }}</p>
        <p class="likes" ng-click="plusOneAdult($index)">+ </p>
        <p class="dislikes " ng-click="minusOneAdult($index)">-</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Called from a `js` file:

```
app.directive('flightInfo', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            flight: '='
                },
        templateUrl: 'js/directives/flightInfo.html'

    };
});
```

Which is called from my main page using:

```
  <div ng-repeat="flight in flights | orderBy:'price'" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <flight-info flight="flight"></flight-info>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your 'plusOneAdult()' and 'minusOneAdult()' methods has to be passed to your directive like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="flight in flights | orderBy:'price'" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <flight-info minus-one-adult-fn="minusOneAdult" plus-one-adult-fn="plusOneAdult" flight="flight"></flight-info>
  </div>
```

And you have to get back these functions in your directive like this:

```
return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            flight: '=',
            minusOneAdultFn:'=',
            plusOneAdultFn:'='
                },
        templateUrl: 'js/directives/flightInfo.html'

    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the method that you are trying to access from `templateUrl` in the `directive`, should be defined under `link` of the same `directive`.

So as per your code, the link method would be as somewhat as below:

```
templateUrl: 'js/directives/flightInfo.html',
link: function(scope, ele, attr) {
    scope.plusOneAdult = function(id) {
        // your code
    };

    scope.minusOneAdult = function(id) {
        // your code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your directive is not linked to any controllers, so your ng-click inside your directive will not work.

You need to create a new controller and move your functions 'plusOneAdult' and 'minusOneAdult' to this new controller and bind it to your directive like this :

```
app.directive('flightInfo', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            flight: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'js/directives/flightInfo.html'
        controller: 'js/directives/flightInfoController.js',
        controllerAs: 'Vm',
        bindToController: true
    };
});
```

Use the functions in your html like this : Vm.plusOneAdult() and Vm.minusOneAdult()